# How to specify team/organization permissions for Trello API token?

Tags: api, trello

I can request a token for a user by visiting the following url:

```
https://trello.com/1/connect?key=<key>&name=appName&response_type=token&scope=read,write&expiration=never
```

However, when I request the token's info through the API, I get a response that looks like this:

```
{
    "id": "...",
    "identifier": "appName",
    "idMember": "...",
    "dateCreated": "2015-10-15T05:21:19.886Z",
    "dateExpires": null,
    "permissions": [
        {
            "idModel": "*",
            "modelType": "Board",
            "read": true,
            "write": true
        },
        {
            "idModel": "*",
            "modelType": "Organization",
            "read": true,
            "write": true
        }
    ]
}
```

I'd like to be able to request a token only grant privileges to a specific organization. But I can't seem to find clear documentation on what kinds of options the `/1/connect` endpoint accepts, or what other method I can use to obtain a token for a specific organization that does not expire.

I could make a machine user with access only to the organization, but it would be a shame to pay for another user account when I only want a subset of the permissions I already have.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that would be possible as you just authenticate against the API as that user and therefore have the ability to see everything that user can. The only way I'm aware of would be (as you suggested) to create a new user and limit what they can see.

Comment: Right, I am just curious because it appears like the functionality is there under the hood to limit permissions of a token to a particular organization, and it would be great if there was some way to hook into that at the time of creation.

Comment: This was originally in the design but pulled because the interface for it felt really bloated.  There's no longer any way to do this, unfortunately.